# Is it possible for two different systems to have the same step response, and vice-versa?

Tags: control-system

Every time I have had to tune a controller (PID, usually) to a process, I have first matched an equivalent first order or second order model by doing some curve fitting on the step responses; and then tuned the controller to the identified model. It has worked well so far, however I wonder if that will always be the case.

Hence my question: if a process is an excellent fit with a model, does that necessarily mean they are nearly equivalent (and therefore controllers tuned to the equivalent model will always work on the real process to some extent) or are some aspects of the system not captured by the step response?

To illustrate, I have recently fit the sum of two different first order systems to a process, because neither a first order or a second order fit. It's a very good fit now, but I do not want to leave anything to luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible for two different systems to have the same step response, and vice-versa?

Of course.

Consider a basic RC low-pass filter driven by a low-impedance source and with a high-impedance load. You could have either R = 100 ohms and C = 10 uF, or R = 1 kohms and C = 1 uF and get the same step response.

Or you could construct an LR dual circuit driven by a current source and get the same step response.

In fact, any first order linear system with the same characteristic frequency will have the same step response.

> if a process is an excellent fit with a model, does that necessarily mean they are nearly equivalent (and therefore controllers tuned to the equivalent model will always work on the real process to some extent)

In my experience there are cases where a first order model appears to fit the step response very well, but the system is actually second-order, and this can affect the ability to achieve good control (when trying to use a controller matched to the first-order model).

> or are some aspects of the system not captured by the step response?

But this doesn't mean the step response did not capture the full behavior. Only that some aspects of the behavior may have only a small effect on the step response, and so be difficult to fit.

On the other hand, of course the mapping from step response to frequency response is only 1-to-1 for linear systems. If your system is nonlinear, the step response will not capture the full behavior.

Comment: I meant two systems with different characteristic frequencies, gains etc, but the second part of your post addresses that. Many thanks. So if some aspects have small effect on the step response, doesn't that mean that it will have small effect on the ability of the controller to control the system? The system is assumed linear.

Comment: The step response is the convolution of the system response with a step input signal. The step input signal has a spectrum with a 1/f behavior. This means it has less energy at high frequencies, so the step response can hide (or at least de-emphasize) high frequency behavior of the system. If you want the control to be good for high-frequency disturbances, the controller optimized based on step response might not be good for that.

Answer (score 0):

A second order system can be aproximated with first order + dead time. YOu should see the the S-shape curve at the begining in second order, that small elay can be modeled as dead time.
If the second order system is very damped, then you can use a first order + dead time as model, but if it has some overshoot and ringing phenomena, then I would say that it can be aproximated by first order